# Revertir archivo a versión anterior en Git

Tags: git

¡Hola!

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, y es que intentando revertir un archivo de Python a una versión de hace unos días en Visual Studio y he escrito:

```
git checkout 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515 -- my_file.py
```

El mensaje que me envía es: **fatal: invalid reference: 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515**

La cosa es que el hash es correcto porque lo he cogido directamente desde "git log", y el archivo no necesita mayor especificación en el path porque estoy dentro de la carpeta (no obstante, lo he especificado en una de las ocasiones por si acaso era ese el error, pero sigo recibiendo el mismo mensaje). De hecho, incluso he probado con otros hash de otros commits por si el problema era ese hash, pero tampoco.

¿Me podríais ayudar con localizar cuál es el error? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Qué versión de git estás usando?

Comment: hiciste un git show con la ruta de ese archivo? también nos acepta si le ponemos el hash de un commit en concreto para ver los cambios de aquel

Comment: tenes en cuenta ?que git checkout  -- single dash here means the previous active branch or detached HEAD.

Comment: Lo mas sencillo es verificar que la revision sea efectivamente lo que estas usando y que esté correcto. Esto te muestra un listado de archivos? `git ls-tree -r 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515`?

Comment: O tambien asi se puede verificar que es una revision: `git cat-file -p 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515` y te debe salir la metainfo de la revision.

Comment: Por cierto, si lo agarraste de `git log`, no significa que necesariamente sea una revision que existe. Si lo agarraste del ID de la revisión (**no de un comentario**), entonces si tendría que estar. Si lo agarraste de un comentario, es posible que no porque podría ser un mensaje de un squash y la revisión original ya se haya llevado a la basura. Otra posibilidad es que sea un clon "superficial" en el que estás trabajando.

Answer (score 0):

No existe un error en el comando que estás intentando ejecutar. El error describe que no existe una referencia valida hacia ese commit.

Para verificar que el código hash haga referencia al commit puedes probar usando `git show 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515` y deberías ver los cambios que este realiza junto con la descripción del mismo. Una vez que lo hayas confirmado, prueba a ejecutar el comando `git checkout 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515 my_file.py`.

Recuerda que si trabajas con un repositorio remoto, antes de hacer cualquier cambio deberías hacer un `git pull origin main`

Si esto realmente no funciona podría existir la posibilidad de que haya un fallo en la base de datos de Git.

> Como recomendación, si trabajas en un proyecto pequeño puedes utilizar la versión corta de los códigos hash, para trabajar de forma más cómoda.

Comment: ¡Hola Juan! Una pregunta: he escrito precisamente ```git show 76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515``` tal y como mencionas, pero me indica: **fatal: ambiguous argument '76410613af2d74b9d7a899f1fbf2d37d5dc7e515': unknown revision or path not in the working tree** ¿qué significa esto? Es que apenas estoy empezando en esto y no entiendo todos los comandos :( ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Eso indica que ese ID que estás especificando no es un objeto en la DB del repositorio (ni revision, ni arbol ni blob). De donde sacaste ese ID? Nos podrías mostrar en la pregunta?